# Reading xls files from R using gdata - precision set by cell format within the spreadsheet

Tags: r, gdata, xls

I am using `read.xls()` from the gdata package to load an excel file into a data frame. In the main it works fine.

However, the data I am after are double precision real numbers. The data appears in the data frame as it was cell formatted in the excel spreadsheet (ie. it is rounded to one decimal place); notwithstanding that the spreadsheet has significantly more precision to the data within it.

My question: is there something I can tweak to get a more precise upload from the excel file using `read.xls()` from the gdata package?, or am I pursuing a lost cause.

Note: I appreciate that I can open the spreadsheet and change the cell formatting and save. But I was hoping to avoid this degree of manual intervention.

Also note: I am working on a mac osx machine.

Comment: You could pass the param `colClasses` and read those columns in as character, then convert after read in?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem like you and I don't think gdata can handle that. I read that xls files are read using the formatted precision (if they have been formatted in Excel) whereas xlsx files are read using the full underlying precision. Try one of the other packages listed on this page:

[http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:data-io:ms_windows&s=excel](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3adata-io%3ams_windows&s=excel)

Answer (score 0):

Try `openxls::read.xlsx` instead of `gdata::read.xls`.
Also a more detailed answer is on to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148580/r-cant-manage-general-formatted-cells-when-reading-libreoffice-generated-xls).